# Fix for VS 2010 Debbugger BUG?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, windows-7, debugging

I have this situation that is really irritating me now. At random times with a success rate of approximately 70-80%, running solutions in Visual Studio 2010 in Debug mode hangs the entire system to the point I need to stick my dirty finger in the restart button of my box.

This is my setup:

- CPU i7 with 8Gb ram
- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- IIS 7

My box it's been running the same configuration for more than a year now, and only recently (1-2 weeks ago) this started happening. I've noticed this happens more often with projects targeting 4.0, and even more with 4.0 ASP.NET web sites and web services. These projects have been working great for a long time and they seem to be working fine on other dev machines, convincing me further more that the problem rests on the machine itself.

This is what I've tried without success:

- Reboot (every time, it's the only way out)
- Repair .NET Framework 4.0 using the web installer
- Repair the VS 2010 installation
- Restart IIS like a mad man.
- Re-Install IIS
- Curse

I figured I wouldn't need to completely uninstall VS and install it again, since I tried the repair option. It seems there are other isolated people that have had the problem before.
See:
[MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vsdebug/thread/b0f8db47-b3f1-4f03-90cd-e9d8fb609548)
[MS Connect thread](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/599221)

Please help. This is the most annoying and frustrating issue I think I've had to dealt with latently. I need something NOT in the margin of:
"Clean Windows 7 install"
or
"Buy a new computer"

Thanks for the help in advance!

[**Update**]
(In response to Madhur's answer)
This is my Debugging->Symbols settings' page.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened once for me too. Try the following:

1. Make sure that you don't have a    symbol path specified in VS under    Tools | Options | Debugging | Symbols    and also, that you don't have the    NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable    set on your machine.
2. Verify that you haven't specified any network shares under the same    setting to server that do not exist    anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I don't think that's the case. See the edit above with the picture of my debugging settings.

Comment: Removing _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: I'm back... the NT_SYMBOL_PATH was in fact the trick. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed/updated any new VS addins or extensions lately?

Occasionally, I've had issues with some . . . even the really popular ones . . . if you have any, uninstall and/or disable them and see if your system returns to normal operation.

Frank

Comment: Disabled all extensions, the only add-in I have left running is R#. Same results. Thanks for the help.